# Create or clear Hashtable instance for each new request of Report in SSRS

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report done via VS2008 SSRS that is uploaded to my Reporting Services Server, that report is called when the event GenerateReport is called (on button click)

Now, I have the following code:

```
Public Shared Dim gruposVolTotal As New System.Collections.HashTable()
Public Shared Dim gruposSeleccion As New System.Collections.HashTable()
Public Shared Dim gruposModVenta As New System.Collections.HashTable()

Dim grupoActual as String = "" 

Public Shared Dim acumuladoSeleccion as Double = 0
Public Shared Dim acumuladoVolTotal as Double = 0
Public Shared Dim acumuladoModVenta as Double = 0
Public Shared Dim acumuladoAnterior as Double = 0


Function Acumulador(ByVal MiGrupo as String, ByVal value as Double, ByVal Campo as String) As Double

If (GrupoActual <> MiGrupo) Then

    If (Campo = "ModVenta") then 
        If (not gruposModVenta.Contains(MiGrupo)) then
            acumuladoModVenta =acumuladoModVenta + value
            gruposModVenta.Add(MiGrupo,acumuladoModVenta )
            Return acumuladoModVenta 
        Else
            Return gruposModVenta(MiGrupo)
        End If 
    End If

    If (Campo = "RunningValue") then 

        acumuladoVolTotal=acumuladoVolTotal + value

        If (not gruposVolTotal.Contains(MiGrupo)) then
            acumuladoAnterior = acumuladoVolTotal + acumuladoAnterior
            gruposVolTotal.Add(MiGrupo, acumuladoAnterior)
        End If 

        Return gruposVolTotal(MiGrupo)

    End If

    If (Campo = "VolumenSeleccion")  then 

        If(not gruposSeleccion.Contains(MiGrupo)) then
            acumuladoSeleccion=acumuladoSeleccion + value
            gruposSeleccion.Add(MiGrupo, acumuladoSeleccion)
            Return acumuladoSeleccion
        Else
            return gruposSeleccion(MiGrupo) 
        End If 

    End If  

End If



End Function
```

What is the problem with this:
If you execute this on VS2008 the results are correct if I change pages (remember on VS2008) the elements persists and that is good.
If you execute this via web application, the first time will execute correctly but the second time if you choose different parameters on the report the values will stay as the 1st time you execute it.

This is because the variables and elements of the hashtables are saved in session so until I dont close the webpage and enter it again the values of these Hashtables and variables will stay the same after the first time you execute it.

If you change the scope of the variables and Hashtables to public, private or directly dim (private) each request (change of pages aka break page) will reset the value of the variables and hashtables.

So the Idea is to utilize the code I posted but what Im asking if is there any way to reset or clear the elements of the hashtables each time I call the report and change the parameters.

I saw in a forum that another user created a new hashtable for each request but those Hashtables wont be garbage collected and that means a lot of memory usage.

Let me know if you need more information.

EDIT:
You change the pages via ReportViewer Control.

I tried using the following code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit()

gruposVolTotal.Clear()
gruposSeleccion.Clear()
gruposModVenta.Clear()

grupoActual = "" 

acumuladoSeleccion = 0
acumuladoVolTotal = 0
acumuladoModVenta  = 0
acumuladoAnterior = 0

End Sub
```

But it seems it deletes it for every change of page and not each time I open the report.